# How to determine that multiple threads call function simultaneously in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

I want to determine whether certain function in C can be called from multiple threads at the same time, in order to understand if I need to protect it with mutexes. The file where the function is implemented and defined does not have any mutex mechanism, so there is a chance that only one thread ever accesses the function but there is a chance that multiple threads do.

I thought to add a thread local storage variable which I increment upon starting the function and decrement upon exiting the function. If, after decrementing, the value of the variable is greater than 0, then multiple threads access the function.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static __thread int threadCounter = 0;

void f(void)
{
    threadCounter++;

    // do something

    threadCounter--;
    printf("threadCounter: %d\n", threadCounter);
}
```

a'm wondering if this solution is sufficient to determine whether multiple threads access a function and whether there are better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: It doesn't look like a thread local variable can successfully detect what you want. It is, by definition, isolated to a single thread.

Comment: You seem to need opposite to a TLS variable - some volatile variable which multiple threads are supposed to have access to. A TLS variable will be visible only by thread in which storage its resides, i.e. each thread will "see" its own version of such variable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I want to know if threads might access the function at the same time.

Comment: There is never a problem with threads accessing "code regions" because code is read-only. There can only be a poblem if code uses non-automatic storage variables. If a function calls other functions, then implementing mutexes should be at the lowest level where  shared data (variables or resources) will be used. I think it is a matter of proper design.

Comment: Note: incrementing `threadCounter` must be atomic. It probably will not be because incrementing it is typically a sequence of fetch, increment, store, where between each instruction interrupts or scheduling can occurr.

Comment: If multiple threads call the function (at all), and there is no mutex, and f operates on things that are not multi-thread safe, then you should put in a mutex unless you can prove from other aspects of the code that the calls will not occur simultaneously (e.g., that `f` is called only after the thread done something else that excludes multiple threads). There are techniques that would reveal if `f` is called simultaneously in experimental runs, but it can happen that `f` is never called simultaneously in experimental runs but does get called simultaneously eventually in practice.

Comment: Adding to what @PaulOgilvie said: It's never about the function: It's always about the _data_. When multiple threads share data, then you should use _the same lock_ to gain permission to access the data in _every function_ where the same data are accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Thread-Local.html) :
"Thread-local storage (TLS) is a mechanism by which variables are allocated such that there is one instance of the variable per extant thread." 
Thus, your solution will always indicate that only one thread access your function at the time even if it's not the case. You should use a variable that is shared between thread. But using a volatile one is still not a good solution because if there are multiple thread accessing it at the time, the value might not be the good one.

In conclusion, I think the better way of doing this would be to setup a mutex and using the pthread_mutex_trylock function to detect if there are multiple threads trying to call your function.

Answer (score 2):

A thread local variable is by definition only visible for the current thread, your solution won't work. But your approach is good. Instead of using a thread local variable you should use a variable protected by a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

This test either is using a local variable, or it isn't thread-safe in itself. In either case, it won't be useful as proof. If you want to use a counter, you have to protect it with something like a mutex or critical section. There's pretty much no way around this.

But there's a another way to do this better though, giving you exact information of who called the function, while at the same time not having to modify the actual function. You can create a "mock" function:

```
#define f() ( print(__func__), f() )
```

This prints the name of the thread callback function, then calls the actual function `f()`. This works because the pre-processor token `f()` is evaluated before any function call.

I wrote the function as a custom one `print`, since you'll still have the problem with multiple thread trying to access stdout at once if you use `printf` etc. So the custom `print` function must contain the means of thread-safety.